# How do I create a timestamp field in sqlite so a Core Data object with a NSDate field is initialized correctly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

After reading [this great tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data) on pre-building a sqlite database to be used by Core Data, I'm still stuck on datetime columns. I've cross-posted my question to try and get some help because I'm stuck on this.

My application uses a pre-built database in a read-only fashion, it is a transit application and the data source is schedule data.  Dates are in the following format (from the data provider): "20110223" (which would be written "Februrary 23, 2011"). I have been reviewing the post and comments talking about the iPhone reference date of 2001, and adjusting date/time values based on a delta of seconds since that time prior to inserting into sqlite. My importer script defines a TIMESTAMP column to store this delta of seconds. An example of the column after being stored would be "319766400".

Here is a snippet of Ruby as an example of what my script does:

```
>> delta_seconds = Time.parse("20110223") - Time.local(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
=> 320112000.0
>> Time.at(delta_seconds)
=> Fri Feb 22 19:00:00 -0500 1980
```

Note that asking for a time from the delta_seconds (Time.at(delta_seconds)) shows the right day of the year (Feb 22) but in the year 1980, which is 10 years after EPOCH---which seems right. In Core Data I've defined my model attribute that maps to this DB field as "NSDate". However, when I fire up the simulator and check the debugger, for each object I ask for the the NSDate field (start_date) as follows:  [object valueForKey:@"start_date"] which gives me "2001-08-21 18:10:19 GMT".  In other words, it doesn't seem to be reading the delta seconds value. If it did, I'd expect it to apply "10 years worth of seconds" in this case and come up with a "2011" year date.

Can you spot something I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions on potential fixes? Thanks! (iOS 4.1 Core Data)

**Or**: can someone post a value from their sqlite database that Core Data reads, from a column that is intended to be the source of a NSDate field? An example value from my database is `320371200` which appears to not work.

Answer (score 4):

The Core Data schema is undocumented and therefore can change without warning. There is no guarantee that the schema from the article from a year ago is still the one used today.

Although, transforming the schema of an existing SQL database to the one used by Core Data seems like the simplest solution but it's actually a fairly difficult and fragile solution.

The better idea is to write a small utility app using the data model and any classes from your main app. Then import the existing SQL and create the Core Data objects and graph from that data. Then take the DB from the utility app and stick in the release app.

It doesn't take anymore time and your schema is current and can be upgraded without worry.

Comment: In general I get your point, but sqlite just stores columns as strings in reality, so I'm just looking for an example of how someone stores a date or datetime or timestamp in a sqlite column so that Core Data will read it. Essentially I've formatted the data column in most ways I can think of, which makes me think I'm doing something else wrong. Creating the utility application to get a string didn't seem worth several hours of work at this point.

Comment: Well I did create the utility application, wasn't so bad. Core Data starts up and the column is `TIMESTAMP` type. I created a record through my entity and called save on it. Using the sqlite console for the application DB I see a value of `320443387.762098`. Using the Ruby console `Time.at(320443387.762098)` gives me `Tue Feb 26 15:03:07 -0500 1980` which is what I'd expect.

Comment: Doing all of the above and making sure to reset the iPhone Simulator data, I was able to get NSDate to parse columns as expected. The NSPredicate data comparison still fails, which is how I started down this path, but that is a separate problem. Thanks!

Comment: I should have mentioned that the Core Data schema is undocumented and thus subject to change without notice. If you generate your own, it is possible that a system update will break your db.